# Why is being relational important in SQL implementations?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by, relational-database, relation

In a book I am reading (Querying SQL Server 2012) the author talks about theory of how databases work. He mentions relations, attributes and tuples etc.

He frequently stresses the fact that some aspect of T-SQL is not relational. Like in the following excerpt:

> Unlike in previous phases where the result was relational, the output
>   of this phase isn’t relational because it has a guaranteed order. The
>   result of this phase is what standard SQL calls a cursor. Note that
>   the use of the term cursor here is conceptual. T-SQL also supports an
>   object called a cursor that is defined based on a result of a query,
>   and that allows fetching rows one at a time in a specified order. You
>   might care about returning the result of a query in a specific order
>   for presentation purposes or if the caller needs to consume the result
>   in that manner through some cursor mechanism that fetches the rows one
>   at a time. **But remember that such processing isn’t relational**. If you
>   need to process the query result in a relational manner—for example,
>   define a table expression like a view based on the query (details
>   later in Chapter 4)—the result will need to be relational. Also,
>   sorting data can add cost to the query processing. If you don’t care
>   about the order in which the result rows are returned, you can avoid
>   this unnecessary cost by not adding an ORDER BY clause.

I would like to know, since every implementation of `SQL` pretty much has an `ORDER BY` clause which makes it non-relational, **why does it even matter** that (the set after `ORDER BY` is used) its not relational anymore since its like that every where?

I can understand if he said it was non standard, for example using `!=` instead of `<>` for inequality because that affects portability etc. but I do not understand why something is better being relational.

Please enlighten.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the author is referring to the use of set theory (which is in his terms "relational") vs. processing row by row with a cursor or similar method.  Accessing the data in a relational way allows the database engine to perform selects/joins/sorts/orders/etc. on entire sets of data where as a cursor will only process one row at a time.  As far as I know, adding an `ORDER BY` clause does not make a query "non-relational", the author is just noting that if you do not care about the order of result set, you can leave that clause out of your query and the database engine will return the data in whatever order it ended up processing it in.

Also note, the `ORDER BY` clause is the last to be executed by the database engine, which means the query is processed in a "relational" way and then ordered at the last minute.  Cursors are starting at the first record and moving through them one by one so the entire operation is performed in a pre-determined order based on your cursor/query definition.

Comment: And cursors and row-by-row processing are much slower than set-based operations.

Comment: The author IS saying that ORDER BY makes it non-relational. He has mentioned this many times. It seems by HLGEM's comment above that the reason the author keeps mentioning it is probably because he wants the readers to differentiate and later understand performance implications.

Comment: MuhammadA is correct and it does - ORDER BY absolutely make a result set NON-RELATIONAL.

Comment: That's simply ridiculous.Let's say that for a big fluke the query engine returns the table already sorted, this would be relational. Instead, if you explicitly ask for such sorting (obtaining the **same** result) it's not relational anymore. It doesn't make any sense. If the order of the rows is irrelevant in the relational model then: why having a particular order makes it not-relational? Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a query being relational in (Querying SQL Server 2012) is that:

### It returns a set that fulfills the query requirements.

But the order of how the result is presented is nondeterministic, meaning it isn't certain and may change for the same database, depending on the underlying process engine.

### ORDER BY makes it deterministic, and thus running the same query on different servers guarantees the same order of the result.

So in that way the order can be the same before and after an ORDER BY clause is added, but it isn't given that they will be equal (e.g. for different patches)